# Couchbase Get operation slows down when the number of incoming threads increases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

**Summary:**

We have a major performance issue with `Spring-Boot 2.0.4` and `Couchbase server 
5.5.1`

We are experiencing a rapid decline in DB response time performance when the number of threads is increasing. [Here is another report about the issue](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-get-operaion-slows-down-with-increased-thread/13188).

**In Details:**

Spring Boot is running with 500 threads:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 500
    max-connections: 500
```

We are using the following dependency:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Our "select" from DB is performed with Spring-Data repository:

```
Cat findFirstByOwnerIdAndNameAndColor(String ownerId, String name, String color);
```

We have an index that is especially for this query:

```
CREATE INDEX `cat_by_ownerId_name_and_color_idx` ON `pets`(`ownerId`,`name`,`color`) WHERE (`_class` = "com.example.Cat")
```

As the number of requests increase, we can see a quick degradation in the time it takes the DB to answer the query.

For example, when running 300 requests per second, the 99's percentile of response time is about **10 Seconds!!** and the 50's percentile is about 5 seconds.

The average size of the returned document is about **300 Bytes**. Meaning that we are trying to extract about 90 Kilobytes per second. A relatively low amount.

**Edit:**

I'm adding here the result of running the same query in the UI of Couchbase:
(In the UI, the query takes 1.75ms to complete).

```
{
 "plan": {
  "#operator": "Sequence",
  "~children": [
  {
    "#operator": "IndexScan3",
    "index": "cats_by_ownerId_name_and_color_idx",
    "index_id": "c061141c2d373067",
    "index_projection": {
      "primary_key": true
    },
    "keyspace": "pets",
    "namespace": "default",
    "spans": [
      {
        "exact": true,
        "range": [
          {
            "high": "\"bf23fa4c-22c3-42ac-b141-39cdc76bb2x5\"",
            "inclusion": 3,
            "low": "\"bf23fa4c-22c3-42ac-b141-39cdc76bb2x5\""
          },
          {
            "high": "\"Oscar\"",
            "inclusion": 3,
            "low": "\"Oscar\""
          },
          {
            "high": "\"red\"",
            "inclusion": 3,
            "low": "\"red\""
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "using": "gsi"
  },
  {
    "#operator": "Fetch",
    "keyspace": "pets",
    "namespace": "default"
  },
  {
    "#operator": "Parallel",
    "~child": {
      "#operator": "Sequence",
      "~children": [
        {
          "#operator": "Filter",
          "condition": "(((((`pets`.`_class`) = \"com.example.Cat\") and ((`pets`.`ownerId`) = \"bf23fa4c-22c3-42ac-b141-39cdc76bb2x5\")) and ((`pets`.`name`) = \"Oscar\")) and ((`pets`.`color`) = \"red\"))"
        },
        {
          "#operator": "InitialProject",
          "result_terms": [
            {
              "expr": "self",
              "star": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "#operator": "FinalProject"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
 },
 "text": "select * from pets where _class=\"com.example.Cat\" and projectId=\"bf23fa4c-22c3-42ac-b141-39cdc76bb2x5\" and name=\"Oscar\" and color=\"red\""
```

}

**EDIT 2**

We also tried to implicitly write the N1ql query, but the outcome is the same. As before, we get many TimeOutExceptions:

```
   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","s":"n1ql","t":7500000,"i":"f8cdf670-d32a-4d74-858c-f9dd9789d264"}; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","s":"n1ql","t":7500000,"i":"f8cdf670-d32a-4d74-858c-f9dd9789d264"}] with root cause

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","s":"n1ql","t":7500000,"i":"f8cdf670-d32a-4d74-858c-f9dd9789d264"}
   at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:131) ~[java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
   at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:127) ~[java-client-2.7.0.jar:na]
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onTimeout(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:166) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber$TimeoutTask.call(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:191) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Is there a way to fix this, or we need a different DB?

Comment: Couchbase can handle much more than that easily. I run in my notebook a load higher than that. What is the size of the machine you are running CB? Can you show some stats of the database during the peek?

Comment: @deniswsrosa According to the statistics page of Couchbase, the "Ops Per Second" range between 40 and 100 during the load test. The test runs on Dell Laptop with 16GB or RAM and the Couchbase DB in in a container. It is important to say that we see same behavior when running  the code in other envs where the DB is in regular mode and not in container. Is is possible that additional Spring-Data configuration is needed?

Comment: Can you execute the same query on CB web console and update your post with the query plan?

Comment: @deniswsrosa added as you suggested

Comment: Everything looks fine, my guess is that your high concurrency is too much for a single query service. Add a second CB instance, and configure it to run in a cluster. (The query service must be running in both of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further investigation, the problem was found in the `Spring-Data` component.

To over come it, we had to move to **non-blocking mechanism**.

We did 2 things:

- All the calls from controller layer down to service & repository layers, were changed to `CompleteableFuture<Cat>`
- To bypass Spring-Data connection to the couchbase, we created a repository class of our own with implementation code that looks something like that:

  ```
  Statement statement = select("*")
          .from(i(bucket.name()))
          .where(x("name").eq(s(name))
                  .and(x("ownerId").eq(s(ownerId)))
                  .and(x("color").eq(s(color)))
                  .and(x("_class").eq(s("com.example.Cat"))));

  CompletableFuture<Cat> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture();
  bucket.async().query(statement)
  ...
  ```

  After we did that, the latency problem disappeared and the performance are about **2 Milliseconds** for query, even during about few hundreds concurrent requests.